# excel vba code is gone after saving copy

Tags: excel, vba

I have a template in which our workers can fill in the data, then the file should be saved as a new file with the Original macros from my template in it
but that doesn't seem to work. The code is always removed in the new file.
The template should be saved too because there's a numbering in it that has to go up with every new file created.

Does anybody know the solution?

```
Public Sub OpslBestand()
On Error Resume Next
Book1_BeforeSave
SavePdfEmail
Dim NieuwRet As Variant
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Copy  
NieuwRet = "P:\Retourformulieren\Excel\" & Range("L2").Value & "-JL-" & Format(Date, "YYYYMMDD") & "-" & Range("Klant").Value
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs NieuwRet, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
ActiveWorkbook.Close
VolgRet
ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Guys i found the problem...  It's this line  ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Copy  this should be Workbook.Sheets.copy and then the macro is in the new file

Comment: When you do a `Sheets.Copy` it copies the sheets (and any macros **in those sheets**) to a new workbook, but won't copy any non-worksheet macros.

Comment: Yes that's the one thanks for your answer too, it was a luck for me that i tried this

Answer (score 2):

If you save the file as `.xlsx`, the macro will be deleted. You need to save the file as `.xlsm` (macro-enabled).

Comment: `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs NieuwRet, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled` will save as a macro-enabled file.